# Apache camel: set cookies for http4 client

Tags: java, scala, apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm having a play around with Apache Camel, and having a few problems transitioning from the 'trivial examples' stage to the 'but with these irritating details' stage. Crucially, how to go in and modify the endpoints explicitly.

In this case, I need to set an auth cookie for the http client. I have a cookie store object, but don't know how to force the client to use it. I've tried using an `HttpClientConfigurer`, but `HttpClient` doesn't expose the cookie store, and it doesn't seem to be being called anyway.

My current code:

```
class CookieClientConfigurer(cs: CookieStore) extends HttpClientConfigurer {
  /**
   * Not very nice, relying on a runtime type check. But what can you do?
   */
  def configureHttpClient(client: HttpClient) {
    client match {
      case client: AbstractHttpClient => client.setCookieStore(cs)
    }
  }
}
```

And invoked by:

```
val username = args(0)
val password = args(1)

val context = new DefaultCamelContext

locally {
  // First we need to grab some authentication cookie stuff!
  val httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient
  val post = new HttpPost("https://rt")
  val nvps = List(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username), new BasicNameValuePair("password", password))
  post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(asJavaList(nvps)))
  httpClient.execute(post)
  val ccc = new CookieClientConfigurer(httpClient.getCookieStore())
  val httpComp = context.getComponent("https4", classOf[HttpComponent])
  httpComp.setHttpClientConfigurer(ccc)
}

val routes = new RouteBuilder {
  def configure() = {
    from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&delay=0&period=10000")
    .to("https4://rt/REST/1.0/ticket/335729/show")
    .to("file://test")

  }
}
context.addRoutes(routes)
context.start()
System.in.read()
context.stop()
```

Any idea how I set the cookie store for the `"https4://rt/REST/1.0/ticket/335729/show"` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

So, on further investigation, the above approach works (it was failing elsewhere), although I'm still unhappy about using a runtime type check to expose the implementation of `HttpClient`, so answers about how to do this better are most welcome!

Comment: Having a similar issue here, with no solution yet, but the docs for http4 claim you should just be able to append ?cookieStore=customInstance to URI